# Translation key-based internationalization with Django

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

Django's default i18n system uses the code language (for instance, English) as translation keys; translations into other languages must be written from that base language. For instance, in a Django template, you would write `{% trans "Hello" %}` and then translate "Hello" into "Bonjour" or "Hola" in the French or Spanish translation file.

This has a major flaw: words that are spelled the same in English cannot be translated differently in other languages. For instance, if I use `{% trans "Fire" %}` in two places of my code, one of which meaning the thing that burns, and the other using a cannon, I would need "Feu" and "Tirer" respectively in French; but Django's i18n forces me to choose a single translation for "Fire".

The translation keys pattern solves this: I use translation keys such as `{% trans "campsite.fire" %}` and  `{% trans "cannon.fire" %}` in my code, that I translate as "Fire" in an English translation file and as "Feu" and "Tirer" respectively in the French file.

Is this a supported use of Django's i18n system? How do I **inject variables** into such translations?

Comment: Django uses po files for the translations.  Keys can be any matching string, or phrase.  the example `{% trans "cannon.fire" %}` will work fine.

Comment: How about if I need to inject a variable in the translation? It looks like it needs to "appear" in the key in order to be available to the translation.

Answer (score 1):

Django supports `contextual markers` for this exact purpose:

```html
<p>{% translate "Fire" context "Literal fire" %}</p>
<p>{% translate "Fire" context "Shooting something" %}</p>
```

would become

```
msgctxt "Literal fire"
msgid "Fire"
msgstr ""

msgctxt "Shooting something"
msgid "Fire"
msgstr ""
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers

Answer (score 0):

The current (yet awkward) way I've made it work is:

- using translation keys such as `{% trans "cannon.fire" %}`
- if I need to use a variable, use a translation key *followed by a variable*:

  `{% blocktrans %}email.password_reset.click_link {{link}}{% endblocktrans %}`

  Then in my translations I can use the link variable as `%(link)s`

It feels like an unintended use, very different from the doc. There may be a more official way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  Keys can be any matching string, or phrase.

template.html

```
{% trans "cannon.fire" %} 
{% trans "campsite.fire" %}
```

po file:

```
msgid "cannon.fire"
msgstr "Tirer"

msgid "campsite.fire"
msgstr "Feu"
```

For varibles in the translation, there is [blocktranslate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktranslate-template-tag) tag that allows variables in the translation.

```
{% blocktranslate %} hello my name is {{ name }} {% endblocktranslate %}
```

Translation of variables in the render context is also possible:

```
{% translate myvar %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please note that translation keys and variables were not independent question. At the time of asking, translation keys and variables felt incompatible, and I was hoping for a single code example with both. Then I came up with the solution I posted as answer below, which feels hacky. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have been annoyed by the same concept from Django Framework just recently. I look at examples from `i18n` library in react and python and other past experiences and there are many reasons one would favor `keys` instead of `plain text` for translations.

Here is one working solution including variables in the text, yet can be a little annoying.

On Django side:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

TEXT = str(_("some.key")).format(count=10)
```

In po file:

```
msgid "some.key"
msgstr "Number of balls: {count}"
```

Usage:

```
>>> print(TEXT)
# Number of balls: 10
```

**I haven't tested this in the Django template** so I can't be sure how it works there, you can probably write plugins for that. But for rest framework usages this should be enough.